# MySQL to JSON (firebase)

Tags: php, mysql, json, object, firebase

I have not found the answer to my problem so I created a post here.

My client has a kennel management application, it will migrate from MySQL to Firebase for better performance.

So I exported the tables in the MySQL database to JSON, and now I want to create a JSON object for each user.

MySQL (JSON):

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "n_adherent": "er654rds32",
            "name": "Michaud",
            "email": "email@email.com",
            ...
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "n_adherent": "yt154fge91",
            "name": "Name2",
            "email": "email@email.com",
            ...
        },
        {...},
        ...
    ],
    "dogs": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "dog1",
            "user": "1",
            ...
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "dog2",
            "user": "1",
            ...
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "dog3",
            "user": "2",
            ...
        },
        {...},
        ...
    ],
    "vaccination": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "dog_id": 1,
            ...
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "dog_id": 1,
            ...
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "dog_id": 1,
            ...
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "dog_id": 2,
            ...
        },
        {...},
        ...
    ],
    "deworming": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "dog_id": 1,
            ...
        },
        {...},
        ...
    ],
    "kennel_maintenance": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "user_id": 1,
            "date": "2016-01-01",
            ...
        },
        {...},
        ...
    ]
}
```

What I would like to get:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "n_adherent": "er654rds32",
            "name": "Michaud",
            "email": "email@email.com",
            "kennel_maintenance": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "date": "2016-01-01",
                    ...
                },
                {...}
            ],
            "dogs": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "dog1",
                    "vaccination": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            ...
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 2,
                            ...
                        }
                    ],
                    "deworming": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            ...
                        }
                     ],
                    ...
                },
            ],

            ...
        },
        {...}, <-- user id = 2
        ... <-- other user
    ]
}
```

or (maybe better):

```
{
    "1": [ <-- user 1
        {
            "id": 1,
            "n_adherent": "er654rds32",
            "name": "Michaud",
            "email": "email@email.com",
            "kennel_maintenance": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "date": "2016-01-01",
                    ...
                },
                {...}
            ],
            "dogs": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "dog1",
                    "vaccination": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            ...
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 2,
                            ...
                        }
                    ],
                    "deworming": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            ...
                        }
                     ],
                    ...
                },
            ],

            ...
        }
    ],
    "2": [ <-- user 2
        ...
    ],
    ... <-- other user
}
```

I used PHP to parse the file but I can not seem to push objects in the user object.

A piece of my code:

```
<?php

$jsonString = file_get_contents('database.json');
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);

$list = array();
$membresGroup = array();
$vaccinationGroup = array();
$vermifugationGroup = array();
$entretiensGroup = array();

// Users
foreach ($data['membres'] as $key) {
  // if($key['id'] === "99995"){ <-- for test I ask for this user

    // Chiens
    foreach ($data['chiens'] as $k) {
      if ($k['user_id'] === "99995") {
        $list[] = $k;

        $key['chiens'] = $list;


        // Vaccination
        $vaccinations = $data['vaccination'];
        foreach ($vaccinations as $object) {
          //var_dump($object);
          if ($object['chien_id'] === $k['id']) {
            if (!array_key_exists($object['chien_id'], $vaccinationGroup)) {
              $newObjectVaccination = new stdClass();

              $newObjectVaccination->chien_id = (int)$object['chien_id'];
              $newObjectVaccination->user_id = (int)$object['user_id'];

              //$vaccinationGroup[$object['chien_id']] = $newObjectVaccination;
            }

            $taskObjectVaccination = new stdClass();

            $taskObjectVaccination->id = (int)$object['id'];
            $taskObjectVaccination->type = (boolean)$object['type'];
            $taskObjectVaccination->chppil = (boolean)$object['chppil'];
            $taskObjectVaccination->date = $object['date'];
            $taskObjectVaccination->date_renouvellement = $object['date_renouvellement'];
            $taskObjectVaccination->parvovirose = (boolean)$object['parvovirose'];

            $vaccinationGroup[$object['chien_id']]->vaccination[] = $taskObjectVaccination;
          }
        }
        $vaccinationGroup = array_values($vaccinationGroup);


        // Deworming
        $vermifugations = $data['vermifugation'];
        foreach ($vermifugations as $object) {
          //var_dump($object);
          if ($object['chien_id'] === $k['id']) {
            if (!array_key_exists($object['chien_id'], $vermifugationGroup)) {
              $newObjectVermifugation = new stdClass();

              $newObjectVermifugation->chien_id = (int)$object['chien_id'];
              $newObjectVermifugation->user_id = (int)$object['user_id'];
              $newObjectVermifugation->vermifugation = array();

              $vermifugationGroup[$object['chien_id']] = $newObjectVermifugation;
            }

            $taskObjectVermifugation = new stdClass();

            $taskObjectVermifugation->id = (int)$object['id'];
            $taskObjectVermifugation->nom = $object['nom'];
            $taskObjectVermifugation->type = $object['type'];
            $taskObjectVermifugation->date = $object['date'];
            $taskObjectVermifugation->date_renouvellement = $object['date_renouvellement'];

            $vermifugationGroup[$object['chien_id']]->vermifugation[] = $taskObjectVermifugation;
          }
        }
        $vermifugationGroup = array_values($vermifugationGroup);

      }
    }

    $entretiens = $data['entretien'];
    foreach ($entretiens as $object) {
      //var_dump($object);
      if ($object['user_id'] === $key['id']) {
        if (!array_key_exists($object['user_id'], $entretiensGroup)) {
          $newObjectEntretiens = new stdClass();

          $newObjectEntretiens->user_id = (int)$object['user_id'];
          $newObjectEntretiens->entretiens = array();

          $entretiensGroup[$object['user_id']] = $newObjectEntretiens;
        }

        $taskObjectEntretiens = new stdClass();

        $taskObjectEntretiens->id = (int)$object['id'];
        $taskObjectEntretiens->date = $object['date'];
        $taskObjectEntretiens->desinfection = (boolean)$object['desinfection'];
        $taskObjectEntretiens->nom_desinfection = $object['nom_desinfection'];
        $taskObjectEntretiens->desinfection_date = $object['desinfection_date'];
        $taskObjectEntretiens->parasitaire = (boolean)$object['parasitaire'];
        $taskObjectEntretiens->nom_antipara = $object['nom_antipara'];
        $taskObjectEntretiens->parasitaire_date = $object['parasitaire_date'];
        $taskObjectEntretiens->autres = (boolean)$object['autres'];
        $taskObjectEntretiens->autres_date = $object['autres_date'];
        $taskObjectEntretiens->autres_note = $object['autres_note'];

        $entretiensGroup[$object['user_id']]->entretiens[] = $taskObjectEntretiens;
      }
    }
    $entretiensGroup = array_values($entretiensGroup);

    // echo json_encode($key, true); <-- I get all dogs of the user 99995
    // echo json_encode($vaccinationGroup, true); <-- I get all the vaccinations dogs User 99995
    // echo json_encode($vermifugationGroup, true); <-- I get all the deworming dogs User 99995
    // echo json_encode($entretiensGroup, true); <-- I have all kennel maintenance from user 99995

  // }
}

// $newJsonString = json_encode($output); <-- $output is not define yet but this is the result of all operations
// file_put_contents('firebase.json', $newJsonString); <-- write result in firebase.json -> to import in firebase app

?>
```

I tried using array_push() function but I don't get the expected result.

Sorry, I'm not really good in PHP, I learn.
If someone could tell me how to proceed manually because it's impossible, there are over 9000 users ...

Thank you for your help, Germain.

Comment: By nesting your data structures, you're going against one of the recommendations from Firebase: [use nested data sparingly](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html). You might want to spend some time in that programming guide anyway, it'll prevent many more headaches down the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the nested structure, you don't have to copy each key/value one by one into the new structure. Instead, parse the data in three cycles, copying complete records:

```
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);
$nested = array(); // output array

// 1. Transform arrays to associative arrays with ID as key
foreach($data as $key => $rows) {
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        $nested[$key][$row['id']] = $row; // use ID as key
    }
}
// 2. Attach records that have a chien_id to corresponding chiens records
foreach($nested as $key => $rows) {
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        if (isset($row['chien_id'])) {
            $nested['chiens'][$row['chien_id']][$key][] = $row;
        }
    }
}
// 3. Attach records that have a user_id to corresponding membres records
foreach($nested as $key => $rows) {
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        if (isset($row['user_id'])) {
            $nested['membres'][$row['user_id']][$key][] = $row;
        }
    }
}
// Now everything should be present under the membres key:
var_export($nested['membres']);
```

If the original data is this:

```
$jsonString = '{
    "membres": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "n_adherent": "er654rds32",
            "name": "Michaud",
            "email": "email@email.com"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "n_adherent": "yt154fge91",
            "nom": "Name2",
            "email": "email@email.com"
        }
    ],
    "chiens": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "nom": "dog1",
            "user_id": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "nom": "dog2",
            "user_id": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "nom": "dog3",
            "user_id": "2"
        }
    ],
    "vaccination": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "chien_id": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "chien_id": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "chien_id": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "chien_id": 2
        }
    ],
    "vermifugation": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "chien_id": 1
        }
    ],
    "entretien": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "user_id": 1,
            "date": "2016-01-01"
        }
    ]
}';
```

Then the output is this:

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'n_adherent' => 'er654rds32',
    'name' => 'Michaud',
    'email' => 'email@email.com',
    'chiens' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'id' => 1,
        'nom' => 'dog1',
        'user_id' => '1',
        'vaccination' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'id' => 1,
            'chien_id' => 1,
          ),
          1 => 
          array (
            'id' => 2,
            'chien_id' => 1,
          ),
          2 => 
          array (
            'id' => 3,
            'chien_id' => 1,
          ),
        ),
        'vermifugation' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'id' => 1,
            'chien_id' => 1,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'id' => 2,
        'nom' => 'dog2',
        'user_id' => '1',
        'vaccination' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'id' => 4,
            'chien_id' => 2,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'entretien' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'id' => 1,
        'user_id' => 1,
        'date' => '2016-01-01',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => 2,
    'n_adherent' => 'yt154fge91',
    'nom' => 'Name2',
    'email' => 'email@email.com',
    'chiens' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'id' => 3,
        'nom' => 'dog3',
        'user_id' => '2',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```